# Quotient of complete linearly topologized ring

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory

The quotient of a complete metrizable group by a closed normal subgroup is always complete, but there are examples to show this need not be true for non-metrizable groups. Here *complete* means *every Cauchy net has a unique limit*. I'm wondering if someone knows an example of this phenomenon for topological rings.

A commutative topological ring $R$ is called *linearly topologized* if there exists a neighborhood basis of $0$ consisting of ideals.

> Does there exist a complete linearly topologized commutative ring $R$ and a closed ideal $I\subset R$ such that $R/I$ is not complete?